# Select all dates between a date range -TERADATA

Tags: database, teradata

I want to select all the date between a given range of dates  in Teradata.

Ex:
sel all_dates where date_range between '2000-01-01' and  '2014-01-01'

Expected output:
2000-01-02 ,
2000-01-03,
.
.
.
2014-01-01

Can anybody suggest what can be the logic for this?

Answer (score 7):

This is a task for a calendar table, there's a builtin:

```
select calendar_date 
from sys_calendar.calendar 
where calendar_date between date '2000-01-01' and date '2014-01-01'
```

Your company probably has it's own calendar to cover specific needs. Ask your DBa where it's located.